# Static variable value different in background agent

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have an app that shows some data and starts a background agent to update live tiles dinamically. Because of live tiles content is created in background agent using some var populated from main thread, I decided (maybe this was a wrong decision, but it's the only one I thought reasonable) to write a class with static variables and properties to share between main thread and background agent. 
Now the problem is I write a variable value in main thread, but when background agent executes finds this value null. Why?
I provide a small example, hopping it's enough for you to understand.

**STATIC PART**

```
public class Vars
{
    public static IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts;
    public static void Test()
    {
        int num = Contacts == null ? -2 : Contacts.Count();
        // num is -2 here because Contacts is null !!
    }
}
```

**BACKGROUND AGENT**

```
public class TileAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
{
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        // It's necessary to use BeginInvoke to avoid Cross-thread errors
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Vars.Test();
        });

        NotifyComplete();
    }
}
```

**MAIN PAGE**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        try
        {
            Vars.Contacts = e.Results
                .Where(.........);
            ContactResultsData.DataContext = Vars.Contacts;
            // Vars.Contacts.Count() = 67 here !!!

            if (Vars.GetTile() != null)
                StartAgent();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            // That's okay, no results
        }
    }
    private void ContactResultsData_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int num = Vars.Contacts == null ? -2 : Contacts.Count();
        // num = 67 here !!
   }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Is there a better way to accomplish my task?
Consider I'm working on Windows Phone from less than one month, so I'm sure I'm still doing very bad things...

**UPDATE**:
After putting correct locks to avoid concurrent read/write from different threads, I decided to put an explicit static constructor to static class

```
public class Vars
{
    static Vars()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("init");
    }
}
```

and this is called everytime background agent is invoked!!
This explains the reason I see my variable as null, but I don't understand: why a static class is recreated every time?
Could it be because background agent is inside a dll project (it's necessary to run it)?
Is there a way to make a single class, created only first time, that can be shared among different threads (are they processes in this situation?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long search, I finally found an [article](http://mstruys.com/2012/01/08/eventiles-from-start-to-finishpart-13/) stating:

> Since our EvenTiles application and its PeriodicTask are running in
>   separate processes, they are completely separated from each other,
>   meaning that they get their own copies of variables they both want to
>   access, even though these variables are defined in a separate project.

So it's impossible to share data between main app and periodic task using "simple" static variables/properties; we must read/write a database or the isolated storage or whatever we please.

I find this crazy, but this is the story.

Comment: UI part and agent part have no shared memory since they are in different processes. Do you have any way to enable inter-process communication in WP7 ?

Comment: @Yamamoto: I never tried using IPC and I don't know if it's possible. I finally used isolated storage to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi Marco i am st-rucked at the same problem. I have tried with adding key-value pair in isolated storage when the OnInvoke() called. And tried to retrieve that key in Main page. But the key is not found..  Will you plz tell me how to use isolated storage for achieving communication between the main app and scheluded task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize access to the shared collection.  Right now one thread can read it (by calling `Count()` while the other writes, and this is very bad.

Comment: I don't think this is the situation. When I read `Vars.Contacts` from background agent noone is writing collection. In my app `Vars.Contacts` is filled only when the app is started and at that moment agent is not running. I'm pretty good in multithreading and I know I must be careful with multiple accesses and I thank you for pointing out, but I'm feeling this is not the problem. Do you agree?

Comment: Anyway, the doubt I can't really explain: why from main app (so, main thread) I can read `Vars.Contacts` (finding items inside) and from the other thread same variable is null? Shouldn't they reference same static variable?

Comment: @Marco: Well, one seems to be looking at `Vars.Contacts`, and the other at `MainPage.Contacts`.  Do you have two variables with the same name?

Comment: No Ben, it was just a typo trying to write sample code. Take a look now. I'm really stuck...

Comment: If you have some time, take a look at my edited question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Marco: Wow, that is weird.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Windows Phone to know why your library project gets unloaded.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Unfortunately I'm quite new to Windows Phone programming, so I can get lost in things that are pretty easy in C# for desktop. Honestly I thought that a background agent (being a loaded dll) run as a thread inside main process, so static class should work as I expected. But this not happens, so I can think either a different process is created every time (so static class instance is different for every process) or that dll gets loaded and  unloaded every time (probably to to save memory?!?).

Comment: Look at the answer I posted. I don't understand this choice, but this is what we must face.

Answer (score 0):

i think that add  volatile modifier to your variable can resolve your problem.

Comment: No, I've already thought about this solution, but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you have some time, take a look at my edited question. Thanks :)