# Share data between main app and periodic task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I post this specific question after the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346576/static-variable-value-different-in-background-agent) I wasn't able to solve.

Briefly: even if I create a static class (with static vars and/or properties), main app and background agent don't use the same static class, but both create a new instance of it; so it's impossible to share data between these projects!!

To test it:

- Create a new Windows Phone application (called **AppTest**)
- Add a ScheduledTask project (called **Agent**)
- In **AppTest** put a reference to project **Agent**
- Create a new Windows Phone Library project (called **Shared**)
- Both in **AppTest** and **Agent** put a reference to project **Shared**

Then use this basic test code.

**AppTest**

```
private readonly string taskName = "mytest";
PeriodicTask periodicTask = null;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Vars.Apps.Add("pluto");
    Vars.Order = 5;

    StartAgent();
}

private void RemoveTask()
{
    try
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Remove(taskName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
private void StartAgent()
{
    periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(taskName) as PeriodicTask;
    if (periodicTask != null)
        RemoveTask();
    periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(taskName)
    {
        Description = "test",
        ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
    };

    try
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(taskName, 
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
    }
    catch (SchedulerServiceException)
    {
    }
}
```

**Agent**

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    if (Vars.Apps.Count > 0) 
        Vars.Order = 1;

    NotifyComplete();
}
```

**Shared**

```
public static class Vars
{
    public static List<string> Apps = null;
    public static int Order;

    static Vars()
    {
        Apps = new List<string>();
        Order = -1;
    }
}
```

When you debug main app you can see that static constructor for static class is invoked (this is correct), but when agent is invoked `Vars` is not "used" but constructor is invoked another time, so creating a different instance.
Why? How can I share data between main app and background agent?
I've already tried to put `Vars` class in agent class and namespace, but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values of static variables are 'instanced' per loaded [App Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), which is a 'subset' of your running process. So static variables have different values per AppDomain, and therefore also per running process.

If you have to share data between processes, you need either to store it somewhere (e.g. a database), or you need to setup some communication between the processes (e.g. MSMQ or WCF).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sound reasonable. But I still find crazy this behaviour: to share some data I need a db or something else... make simple things difficult!! Imagine: I need to create a collection derived from phone contacts (it should be hundreds items long) and use it in main app to show data and in background agent to perform some task (e.g. live tile update), so I have to save derived list in db or isolated storage and ther reload it (so serializing and deserializing) everytime I want to use it... I have no words...

Comment: I'm not sure now - do you have 1 application or multiple?

Comment: One single application, this is what makes me going crazy: shouldn't background agent be a thread inside main process? Shoudn't they use same `App Domain`?

Comment: If you have a single application, then yes, you should be able to 'share' data using a static. If it is the best way, that is another question, but yes, it should work. As long as the loaded assemblies are in the same app-domain/process.

Comment: Did you try my code? Try (if you have time, lol) and let me know... I'm really stuck :(

Comment: I do not have windows phone development installed at the moment, so no luck there. But I do see a call to a ScheduledActionService class, and some googling gave me http://anindita9.wordpress.com/tag/background-process-in-wp7/. I get the impression that scheduled task/background agent on WP7 is a separate process, since it runs separate from the main application. So that would mean: yes, they are different applications/processes, so yes, different static values.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, I'm taking a look at the link you provide :)

Comment: I think I will accept your answer soon, after some deeper research. Look at the answer I posted: you were right :)

Comment: Yes, background processes are separate processes from the main app.  Since this is the case, they cannot share variables that are not saved to isolated storage or in a database or web service.  I'm using a background agent in one of my apps, and it looks to me like Maarten's answers are correct.  Additionally, if you need to share a class or model between the app and a background agent, you will need to create a third project in the solution, add any shared classes, and both the main and background projects will import the third project.

Comment: @RichHopkins: yes, but those classes are not "shared" in the sense they are the same. Both in main app and agent a different instance is created, so you can share "code" but not instance. I don't like this Microsoft choice, but I cannot do anything else than accept it :)

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I didn't mean to imply shared instances, but shared classes, as I stated.  Just trying to share a tip that took me a good bit of searching around to get.

Answer (score 8):

Easiest thing is to use Isolated storage.  For example, from the main app:

```
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyData"))
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["order"] = 5;
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
//...
```

and in the agent:

```
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyData"))
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        order = (int)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["order"];
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

// do something with "order" here...
```

You need to use Process-level synchronization and Mutex to guard against data corruption because the agent and the app are two separate processes and could be doing something with isolated storage at the same time.

Comment: MS recommends not using IsolatedStorageSettings for this lest the data get corrupt.  See "Communication Between Foreground Application and Background Agent" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: @MarkSowul Yet, they don't detail how the data can get corrupt.  If "corruption" is due to lack of synchronization, the mutex will guard against that.  If not, random unexplained corruption is a *huge* concern...

Comment: Considering they call out the use of a Mutex for isolated storage files, that would imply there's something else they're concerned about..

Comment: @MarkSowul That's the really scary part--implying there's random corruption you can't do anything about (highly suspect).  BTW, I've done the `IsolatedStorageSettings` guarded by a `Mutex`; never had any corruption.  Had I not used `Mutex`, I would have expected corruption.  If it's just the lack of synchronization that can cause corruption (and it would) then `Mutex` would get rid of the possibility.

Comment: Maybe there's buffer flushing, or some similar lower-level management, that is specifically not safe to use across multiple processes (vs multiple threads in just the app itself)...in other words, stuff that happens outside the Mutex.  For example one can't actually explicitly "open" or "close" the IsolatedStorageSettings, but only save...

Comment: ...and if you go to MSDN for the class itself, you'll see a similar note vis-a-vis Silverlight: If you have multiple instances of an out-of-browser application running on the same computer and you use IsolatedStorageSettings, you may experience unexpected behavior when reading and saving settings. If this is a scenario for your application, consider using the IsolatedStorageFile APIs instead of IsolatedStorageSettings. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: In my personal painful experience, I store the data in IsolatedStorage Settings and load the data in playback agent. Sometimes it is correct and sometimes it is wrong. I spent the last two days fixing this issue. For your own good, "DO USE TAG PROPERTY TO COMMUNICATE" with playback agent!!!

Comment: @cwhsu Could you please elaborate on this? Where do I find this tag property?

Comment: new AudioTrack(new Uri(datum.URL, UriKind.Absolute),
                                        datum.Name1,
                                        datum.Name2,
                                        String.Empty,
                                        new Uri(datum.Image, UriKind.Absolute),
                                        "This is the TAG",
                                        DefaultPlayerControls);

Comment: By the way, if you really want to use file to communicate between foreground and background, use file along with mutex!

Answer (score 3):

After a long search, I finally found an [article](http://mstruys.com/2012/01/08/eventiles-from-start-to-finishpart-13/) stating:

> Since our EvenTiles application and its PeriodicTask are running in
>   separate processes, they are completely separated from each other,
>   meaning that they get their own copies of variables they both want to
>   access, even though these variables are defined in a separate project.

So it's impossible to share data between main app and periodic task using "simple" static variables/properties; we must read/write a database or the isolated storage or whatever we please.

I find this crazy, but this is the story.

Comment: Why is that "crazy".  your app exits when you go back or go to another app; what would you expect your background agent to be able to access if the app is no longer running?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: well, your app exits, but that does not mean it's "closed", maybe it's just paused and then restarted, but can continue to "live"... that's what I have in my mind; if this was true, the app could be "waken" and notified to run background agent as a separate thread, not as a separate process. I know, it's not the reality; but this is what I thought when I approached background agents and I was definitely wrong ;) Anyway if this was the model, sharing data between main app and agent would be really really easier!!

Comment: Yep, it doesn't always mean exits; but it can and will exit the application once switched to another application.  This can happen while the program is executing as well e.g. when the phone rings.  When this happens it's called "tomb-stoning".

Answer (score 2):

MS recommends the following:

### Communication Between Foreground Application and Background Agent

Passing information between the foreground application and background agents can be challenging because it is not possible to predict if the agent and the application will run simultaneously. The following are recommended patterns for this.

1.For Periodic and Resource-intensive Agents: Use LINQ 2 SQL or a file in isolated storage that is guarded with a Mutex. For one-direction communication where the foreground application writes and the agent only reads, we recommend using an isolated storage file with a Mutex. We recommend that you do not use IsolatedStorageSettings to communicate between processes because it is possible for the data to become corrupt.

2.For Audio Agents: Store custom data in the Tag property of the AudioTrack class. For notifications from the audio agent to the foreground application, read the Tag property in the PlayStateChanged event handler. To pass data from the foreground application to the audio agent, read the Tag property of the current track in the implementation of the OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer, AudioTrack, PlayState) method.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I did a lot of research on communicating between foreground app and Playback Agent, and finally found out that using Tag property is "the very correct" way!!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Peter Ritchie, sorry but can you be a bit more specific? What is this?

Comment: Actually, the original wording from the OP seems to encourage using it?

Comment: Sure it works, e.g. here snippet from Background Audio Agent code..              string newTag = "new msg";  AudioTrack track = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track;
                    track.BeginEdit();
                    track.Tag = newTag;
                    track.EndEdit();