# WP7 how to detect when audio track goes to end?

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, audio, agent

I'm using `BackgroundAudioPlayer` agent in my Windows Phone 7 application. When the track end, the agent side receives `TrackEnded` event, but UI side doesnot receive any events.

Also, when I intentionally set audio track 's position to its end, then call `Play()`, the agent side receives `TrackEnded` event (because the track has come to an end), but the UI side does receive `Stopped` in its `PlayStateChanged` handler. So weird !

How to let UI know that an track has come to an end ? Communicating through isolated storage is not my favorite !

Comment: In your app with UI, have you subscribed to the [`PlayerStateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer.playstatechanged(v=vs.105).aspx) event of [`BackgroundAudioPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer.instance(v=vs.105).aspx) instance? this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_HowtoPlayBackgroundAudio) shows how to hook it all up.

Comment: @NeilTurner yes, of course, I already subscribed to the PlayStateChanged event in the UI side

Comment: When inside the `PlayStateChanged` event handler, does `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.TrackEnded` occur? I see others have had issues with it, and WP8 has new ` IntermediatePlayState` info as part of its `EventArgs` to assist.

Comment: @NeilTurner the TrackEnded event is only informed in the agent side!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From research and a little testing, using Isolated Storage as a middle-man between Background and Foreground instances of the `BackgroundAudioPlayer` is still the only route for Windows Phone 7. The options are mentioned here (which I know you're aware of)...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/10/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-2.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11419680/247257

This was also confirmed by Peter Torr who said:

> For example, the agent may need to tell the foreground “I just started pre-downloading the next track,” or “I updated a database table and you should refresh your state”. Such notifications are impossible to create with Windows Phone OS 7.1; at best you can model them by using polling techniques, but this approach is inefficient and prone to errors.

The only good news is that in the same post, he gives a solution (using named events for IPC) for Windows Phone 8 which is a lot more reliable...

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents.aspx