# How to use isolated storage pass data to background agent in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Below coding i found in [Share data between main app and periodic task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390084/share-data-between-main-app-and-periodic-task) but it can't work and getting error.

Any idea or help?

in the main page

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Threading;

    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyData"))
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["order"] = 5;
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
```

and in the agent:

```
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyData"))
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        order = (int)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["order"];
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: 1)invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.2)types of nameplace definition, or end of file expected

Comment: I guess your agent is written in C++/CX and you are trying to use C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you, you can use a separate library project for this task that will taking care to communicate in between both of applications; such as foreground and  background app.

You must have three projects in your application.

1) UI Aapplication (Foreground App)

2) Project Library (isolated communication [Rear/Write] operation)

3) Background agent app.

See the following diagram here to get cleared.

[image: architecture diagram]

[image]
Hope it helps