# Sharing a DTO between Windows runtime component and a windows store class library

Tags: c#, windows

I have a Windows store app that uses Sqlite as a database component. The sqlite database is wrapped in a Windows class library project. I want to reference this dll in a Background Task (A win RT component type project) and call some database update methods. Here is a sample class in the library, that I tried using in the Win RT Component and received 
this error

Method ServerDataProvider.GetPersonProxy() returns 'WindowsSqlite.PersonProxy', which is not a valid Windows Runtime type.  Methods exposed to Windows Runtime must return only Windows Runtime types.

```
class PersonProxy
{
  public string Name;
  public int Id;
}
```

The data types in this class are "mappable" to the Win RT Types, as per MSDN. When I add this same class in the Win RT Component project, everything compiles.

Any pointers would be of great help,.

Many Thanks,
Prea

Comment: Have you tried putting these data transfer types into a portable class library and sharing them between the two other projects?

Comment: @PeterRitchie yes I tried putting them in a portable library and referencing it in both Projects, but I still get the same error. The same class, if it is included in the Background Task project, compiles.. This is such a bummer since I already have database related stuff in a separate class library which I could have referenced in the Background Task. Now it seems I will either have to repeat the database code (taking only what is required) or Transfer the data using a json file or app Settings

Comment: here is the post that says so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390084/share-data-between-main-app-and-periodic-task

Comment: I think the question should be, can a Background Task reference a class library and use the functionaliy when running..? Theoretically shouldn't the process backgroundTaskHost.exe be able to load a separate library to call some methods on it via a Background Task?