# Windows Phone 8.1: Pass values from Background Task

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I have a native Windows Phone 8.1 application where I read each 30 minutes (TimeTrigger) some values from url.

But how can I pass those values from background task to the foreground task?

I made a custom static event carrying a string, which is working when I read the value right after the task registration.
But when I call the background task from the debug Lifecycle Events menu, the event is null (nobody is listening).

Why?

*Or is there some other way I can notify the foreground task that the backgroundtask has obtained the value (I know I can pass the value between the threads via ApplicationData or file).*

Thanks

Comment: In WP8 the only known way to me was to save the data to be exchanged between a scheduled task and the main application in an IsolatedStorageFile. IsolatedStorageSettings didn't work. I don't know if this applies to WP 8.1 but here are some details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390084/share-data-between-main-app-and-periodic-task