# How to persist data in a static variable when shared across library?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, static, portable-class-library, class-library

I have a main application (Windows Phone to be precise ). And its referencing another class library I have created. I have created a static variable in this class library and am changing those variables from the main application. The variable value is shown correctly when accessed from the main application but when i access the same variable from the class library itself then its showing a different value. Below is my code.

A class in My class library:

```
public class PlayerQueue
    {
        public static bool LoopStatus;

        public static PlayerQueueTrack GetNextSong(String audioTrackId)
        {
            if (LoopStatus)
                return audioTracks[audioTrackId];
        }
    }
```

Tap Method in my Windows Phone application:

```
 private void loopButton_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerQueue.LoopStatus = true;
    }
```

After my tap method is executed in phone application, if the GetNextSong() method is called from within the class library then the LoopStatus is shown as false even though it was set as true.

So the value in `PlayerQueue.LoopStatus` when accessed from Windows phone application is different and `PlayerQueue.LoopStatus` when accessed from a class library which contains the `PlayerQueue.LoopStatus` is giving a different value.

Can anyone please tell me how i can persist the data across the library and the application ?

EDIT:
Adding the class in the class library from which am making the GetNextSong() call

```
public class AudioPlayer : AudioPlayerAgent
{
    private static volatile bool _classInitialized;

public AudioPlayer()
{
    if (!_classInitialized)
    {
        _classInitialized = true;
        // Subscribe to the managed exception handler
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
            Application.Current.UnhandledException += AudioPlayer_UnhandledException;
        });
    }
}

protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
{
    PlayerQueueTrack playerTrack = PlayerQueue.GetNextSong(id);
}
```

}

Comment: It should work. There is something else in your program that you don't show in the post.

Comment: Honestly there is nothing else. I have also added the class from where am making the GetNextSong() method call in which the variable "LoopStatus" is returning false even though i have set it to true from the windows phone application method.

Comment: When i access the LoopStatus variable anywhere in the windows phone application, it is returning the correct value that i had set it. But only when i access it from the class library its returning the default false. So that means both the class library and windows phone application are being given different instances of PlayerQueue class right ?

Comment: @Bitsian If i can suggest just pass `LoopStatus` value as parameter from your Tap function to your `GetNextSong` function.

Comment: Ya thats not possible actually :( The OnPlayStateChanged method which is like an event raised when a player's state is changed. And if i access the value of LoopStatus in OnPlayStateChanged method then it is also false because that method is in the class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static values are persisted across an application domain. As long as your application is running and didn't create a new appdomain it will remain the same. Or another piece of code is changing it.

Windows Phone 8 is a bit more complex because event tiles and the application tend to run in different app domains:

[Static variable value different in background agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346576/static-variable-value-different-in-background-agent)

If you have a static value across event tiles and background processes your last remaining option is to store it to a persistent data store / isolated storage.

Comment: I eventually had no other option but to store the data in Isolated Storage !! Thanks for your help !